# Comparing an array of item with two attributes

Tags: java, logic

I met a question that I have problem solving in Java. The question goes like this:

John was asked to design a program that picks a bottle. The program has to decide from 4 bottles: Bottle A, B, C, D. There might be holes in some of the bottles. Therefore, the program must prevent picking bottles which have holes and also the largest bottle so as to carry as much water as possible.

```
Bottle A - has holes and can hold 5 litres of water
Bottle B - no holes and can hold 2 litres of water
Bottle C - no holes and can hold 3 litres of water
Bottle D - no holes and can hold 1 litre of water`
```

I have tried programming it in Java using a nested for loop. However, it does not give me the correct answers.

```
Bottle[] bottles = {a, b, c, d};
Bottle chosen = a;
for(int i=0; i<bottles.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<bottles.length; j++)
    {
        if(bottles[i].capacity < bottles[j].capacity && bottles[j].noHoles())
        {
            chosen = bottles[j];
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(chosen.id);
```

Comment: what is `Bottle chosen = a;` and `chosen.id`? Figuring out your code, it should be `chosen = null;`

Comment: Do you only want to choose one bottle? If so, you only need one loop, not nested loops.

Comment: why you use nested `for` loop? did the question ask you to compare capacity ?

Comment: If a is an instance of bottle class then If(bottles.noHoles()) should suffice. if you are going in a loop then there is a need to continuously fetch a bottle continously which is not your problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you are picking a single thing, all you need is a single loop. Second, since one of the properties (namely, `noHoles()`) is compared to a fixed value (i.e. it must be `true`) the only thing left for comparison is the capacity.

Hence, the algorithm looks like this:

- Set the best bottle to `null`
- Make a single loop that goes through bottles one by one
- Check if the current bottle has no holes; if it does, continue the loop
- Check if the best bottle is `null`. If it is, set `best` to `current`
- Otherwise, compare the capacities of `current` and `best`, and set `best` to the bottle with larger capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing so I am not sure if I answered what your asked. But if you only need to check if the `Bottle` has holes or not, you do not need to use nested `for` loops. I'd recommend use enhanced for loop. something like this:

```
for(Bottle bot : bottles){
      if(bot.noHoles()) //i assume noHoles is bollean type
          System.out.println(bot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as:
   `Bottle[] bottles = {a, b, c, d};
    Bottle chosen = bottles[0];
    for(int i=1; i<bottles.length; i++)
    {
    if(bottles[i].noHoles() && bottles[i].capacity > chosen.capacity)
       chosen = bottles[i];
    }`
     `System.out.println(chosen.id);`